# указать другое для запоминания логина

Tags: asp.net-core

У меня сейчас после авторизации запоминаются поля `username` и `password`. А мне нужен `login` вместо `username` (форма одна и та же). Спасибо за ранее. Буду рад ссылке или чему-то наводящему т. к. сам не нашел никакой информации на эту тему.

Comment: Вы создаете юзера через userManager?

Comment: @FX_Sektor да, кончно